# Passing received data to "input" function in python

Tags: python, sockets, server

Okay, so I createda socket server in python and I want when someone connects to it to run an application on the sever but which is user controlled. I'll try to explain better with the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import select
import os
from time import sleep

class SocketServer:
    """ Simple socket server that listens to one single client. """

    def __init__(self, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 2010):
        """ Initialize the server with a host and port to listen to. """
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock.bind((host, port))
        self.sock.listen(1)

    def close(self):
        """ Close the server socket. """
        print('Closing server socket (host {}, port {})'.format(self.host, self.port))
        if self.sock:
            self.sock.close()
            self.sock = None

    def run_server(self):
        """ Accept and handle an incoming connection. """
        print('Starting socket server (host {}, port {})'.format(self.host, self.port))

        client_sock, client_addr = self.sock.accept()

        print('Client {} connected'.format(client_addr))

        stop = False
        while not stop:
            if client_sock:
                # Check if the client is still connected and if data is available:

                os.system("python vuln.py")

                # try:
                #     rdy_read, rdy_write, sock_err = select.select([client_sock,], [], [])
                # except select.error:
                #     print('Select() failed on socket with {}'.format(client_addr))
                #     return 1

                if len(rdy_read) > 0:
                    read_data = client_sock.recv(255)
                    if len(read_data) == 0:
                        print('{} closed the socket.'.format(client_addr))
                        stop = True
                    else:
                        print('>>> Received: {}'.format(read_data.rstrip()))
                        if read_data.rstrip() == 'quit':
                            stop = True
                        else:
                            client_sock.send(read_data)
            else:
                print("No client is connected, SocketServer can't receive data")
                stop = True

        # Close socket
        print('Closing connection with {}'.format(client_addr))
        client_sock.close()
        return 0

def main():
    server = SocketServer()
    while (True):
        server.run_server()
    print 'Exiting'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my socket server, which always runs and cand establish multiple connections.

```
print("Please tell me what's your age")

age = input('> ')

sleep(1)
print("Damn man, sometimes I wish I was %s" % age)
sleep(1)
```

and this is the app which I want to run on the server and let the user who connects with netcat for example see the same prompt and have the same functionality but on the server.

Comment: And what have you tried?  This is a fairly straightforward job for `subprocess` with a pty.

Comment: All that's seen in the code, how do you do that with subprocess and pty?

Comment: That’s over-broad—you need to ask about your own attempt at doing so.

Comment: I am new at trying to do this and I just want to make it work and learn something, thus I have no idea where to start and also what I presented here I would is indeed a good start.